# Pandas get_dummies include columns for missing categories?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
})
df1_dummy = pd.get_dummies(df1)
print(df1_dummy)
```

I then got:

```
    id  category_A  category_B  category_C  category_D
0    1           1           0           0           0
1    2           0           1           0           0
2    3           0           0           1           0
3    4           0           0           0           1
```

However, I have another DataFrame which looks like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
})
df2_dummy = pd.get_dummies(df2)
print(df2_dummy)
```

I got:

```
   id   category_A  category_B
0   1            1           0
1   2            1           0
2   3            0           1
3   4            0           1
```

And my problem is, is there any ways to generate df2_dummy automaticly looks like df1_dummy which has the columns ['category_C', 'category_D'] and the values are both zero, looks like:

```
df2_dummy:

    id  category_A  category_B  category_C  category_D
0    1           1           0           0           0
1    2           1           0           0           0
2    3           0           1           0           0
3    4           0           1           0           0
```

I'd appreciate it if someone can help!

Comment: Maybe reindex helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df2`'s categories are the same categories as `df1`, you can "sync" them so `pd.get_dummies` handles the missing categories appropriately:

```
pd.get_dummies(
    pd.Categorical(df2['category'], categories=df1['category'].unique()))

   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0
```

Here's what you would do:

```
df2['category'] = pd.Categorical(
    df2['category'], categories=df1['category'].unique())
pd.get_dummies(df2)

   id  category_A  category_B  category_C  category_D
0   1           1           0           0           0
1   2           1           0           0           0
2   3           0           1           0           0
3   4           0           1           0           0
```

Comment: Aha, this really helped a lot. Thanks for solving my problem :)